# Proc Tabulate: Reordering a Formatted Variable

Tags: sas

I created a day variable using the following code:

```
DAY=datepart(checkin_date_time); /*example of checkin_date_time 1/1/2014 4:44:00*/
format DAY DOWNAME.;
```

Sample Data:

```
   ID   checkin_date_time      Admit_Type     BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO
   1      1/1/2014 4:40:00        ICU               456
   2      1/1/2014 5:64:00        Psych             146
   3      1/1/2014 14:48:00       Acute             57
   4      1/1/2014 20:34:00        ICU              952
   5      1/2/2014 10:00:00        Psych            234
   6      1/2/2014 3:48:00        Psych             846
   7      1/2/2014 10:14:00       ICU               90
   8      1/2/2014 22:27:00        ICU              148
```

I want to analyze some data using Proc Tab where day is one of the class variables and have the day of week appear in chronological order in the output; however, the output table begins with Tuesday. I would like it to start with Sunday. I've read over the the following page http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/085-2011.pdf and tried the proc format invalue code but it's producing a table that where the "day of week" = "21". Not quite sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

```
 proc format;
 invalue day_name
 'Sunday'=1
 'Monday'=2
 'Tuesday'=3
 'Wednesday'=4
 'Thursday'=5
 'Friday'=6
 'Saturday'=7;
 value day_names
 1='Sunday'
 2='Monday'
 3='Tuesday'
 4='Wednesday'
 5='Thursday'
 6='Friday'
 7='Saturday';
 run; 

 data Combined_day;
 set Combined; 
 day_of_week = input(day,day_name.);
 run; 

 proc tabulate data = Combined_day;
 class  Day Admit_Type;
 var BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO ;
 format day_of_week day_names.;
 table Day*Admit_Type, BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO * (N Median); 
 run;
```

[image]

Comment: @Parfait, thanks for the help - see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you are confusing actual values with displayed values (i.e., formats). Specifically, `datepart` extracts the date portion out of a date/time field. Then, applying a `format` only changes how it is *displayed* not actual underlying value. So below *DAY* never contains the character values of `'WEDNESDAY'` or `'THURSDAY'` but original integer value (`19724` and `19725`).

```
DAY = datepart(checkin_date_time);   // DATE VALUE
format DAY DOWNAME.;                 // FORMATTED DATE VALUE (SAME UNDERLYING DATE VALUE)
```

Consider actually assigning a column as weekday value using [`WEEKDAY`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0ahi8tk3trkv5n173sil9hd7c62.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) function. Then apply your user-defined format for `proc tabulate`.

```
data Combined_day;
    set Combined;

    checkin_date = datepart(checkin_date_time);  // NEW DATE VALUE (NO TIME)
    format checkin_date date9.;

    checkin_weekday = weekday(checkin_date);     // NEW INTEGER VALUE OF WEEKDAY
run;


proc tabulate data = Combined_day;
    class checkin_weekday Admit_Type;
    var BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO ;
    format checkin_weekday day_names.;           // APPLY USER DEFINED FORMAT

    table checkin_weekday*Admit_Type, BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO * (N Median); 
run;
```

[image: Table Output]